# XHTML 1.0 Transitive, is there a tool that can refactor HTML?

Tags: asp.net, html, xhtml, automated-refactoring

I have a Asp.net web application running with the following config setting.

```
<xhtmlConformance mode="Legacy"/>
```

This limits use of AJAX and compatibility with multiple browser.

If my understanding is correct, the HTML code of the aspx pages need to be fixed to comply with XHTML 1.0 Transitional.

There are alot of HTML pages, ~1000, is there a tool that could speed up this process?

Comment: Are you actually experiencing AJAX problems?

Comment: FYI - It's "XHTML 1.0 Transitional", not "Transitive". But seeing that it is XML, a simple XSLT program could transform it to HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Tidy](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/) is probably the best there is, but I've never been entirely happy with it, and if the code is that bad it is usually a sign that it needs rewriting anyway.

Comment: can Tidy work with aspx files? it wants me to remove the server controls(custom ones) from my aspx files before tidying them.

Answer (score 2):

The [DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSToolkit.html) is a tool for automating mass change to large source code bases.

DMS uses language-precise parsers to read source code, and langauge-precise analyzers to determine meaning or problems.  One can use [Source to Source program transformations](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/ProgramTransformation.html) to carry out changes of the form, "if you see *this*, replace it by *that*" stated in terms of language surface syntax.  The patterns are driven by the language grammar and are applied to ASTs generated by DMS parsers.

DMS has language front ends for a variety of languages, including HMTL and XHTML.

DMS has been used on "dirty" HTML (even that has a precise definition!) to refactor it.  It might be a pretty good match for your fix-1000-pages problem.

Answer (score 1):

Are the pages currently in HTML or XHTML? If they are in HTML, *leave them*. There is no benefit to using XHTML.

Comment: I doubt that any **legacy** web app would be HTML 5.

Comment: Given that the original question is about legacy HTML and the HTML 5 specification is not finalized yet, I'd be surprised if they have HTML 5 compliant markup.

Comment: They are not in HTML 5, and I need to make them valid XHTML 1.0, closed tags etc, like described here 

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XHTML#Valid_XHTML_documents

and i'm looking for a tool to speed things up, just like CodeIt.Right can do in code behind.

Comment: Edited: made more general to ask for HTML in general. To recap, if you have HTML, keep it that way.

Answer (score 1):

HTML 5 supports the use of XML syntax so moving from legacy HTML to XHTML is going to have some long term advantages since you pages will be syntactically correct which could allow for an easier move to HTML 5 or XHTML 2 when they are completed.

As noted by [David Dorward](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2913183/xhtml-1-0-strict-is-there-a-tool-that-can-refactor-html/2913307#2913307) in his answer, [HTML Tidy](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-tiptidy.html) might be useful if you have fairly constant HTML markup, but given the number of pages I would be surprised if that was the case. If you do a Google search for "[legacy html to xhtml tool](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=legacy+html+to+xhtml+tool&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=)" some other tools turnup that might be worth looking into.

Another thing to take into account is how the pages are written. Most legacy HTML pages don't have a clear separation between markup and styles so you are likely going to have to pull styling out for CSS files that automatic tools can be hit or miss with. As such, you might be looking at a situation where the best thing to do is sit down with the site and run the pages though a validator such as the [W3C Markup Validation Service](http://validator.w3.org/) or use a browser plug-in to do the testing while you are browsing through the site. The [Html Validator](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/249/) for Firefox is pretty good and this is generally how I test web applications. The downside to this that if there is any HTML that is being generated in the code-behind pages, you may not encounter it during testing.

Comment: Thanks, in this case the CSS is already pulled out of the HTML files, the main problems I'm looking at is tags not properly closed, tags in upper case that should be in lower case

Comment: "HTML 5 uses XHTML syntax" -- really? I don't think so.

Comment: @Tomalak - I went back and read the document that I read that in (http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-html5-diff-20080122/#syntax) and it looks like I was half right in my response since XHTML is XML. HTML5 supports two forms of syntax, one of which is specific to HTML5, and XML syntax. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: @GenEric35 - In regards to the tags it could be hit or miss in a tool that can close them; however, converting to lowercase is something that you might be able to do that with regular expressions.

Comment: yes, found that in this case it's going to be a combination of a few methods, find/replace, regular expression, visual studio can do a bit of formating in the aspx files.